# Lapply function to list of data.tables by reference silently

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I have a list of data.tables and I want to apply a function to each data.table. I things set up to use `:=` inside an lapply function. Everything works fine and my outputs are updated by reference, but my function also prints to the console. This is part of a much larger project and printing this step to the console is not ideal.

How do I run this 'silently' without printing? Is there a better way to structure the workflow / code?

```
dt1 <- data.table(a = rnorm(1:10),
           b = rnorm(1:10))

dt2 <- data.table(a = rnorm(1:10),
                  b = rnorm(1:10))

dts <- list(dt1, dt2)

lapply(dts, function(dt) {
  dt[, ':=' (c = a + b)]
})

dts
```

`dts` now has a C column, but the outputs were displayed in the console. This code chunk is called from another function.

Comment: If you want to do this silently, then use `walk`

Comment: Can you assign it `<-` to `dts` or wrap it in `invisible()`?

Comment: @Matt Yes assigning it works to suppress output. I was avoiding `<-` since it is not needed for the evaluation of the code but does achieve the desired outcome.

Comment: @akrun I meant run silently as in does not print to the console. I wasn't explicitly asking how to do this without assigning a variable, I just didn't have my code set up to do this.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Just wanted to clear that doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the `lapply` call which will suppress the output

```
dts <- lapply(dts, function(dt) {
  dt[, ':=' (c = a + b)]
})
```

Comment: I think this is the most straightforward solution. There don't appear to be any performance differences although I haven't tested this extensively. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use a for loop

```
for(dt in dts) dt[, ':='(c = a + b)]
```

Comment: This is also a good method. I rarely use `for` loops anymore, but sometimes they are the most straightforward way of approaching a problem.

Answer (score 2):

We. can use `walk` which will not print anything into the console

```
library(purrr)
walk(dts, ~ .x[, `:=`(c = a + b)])
dts
#[[1]]
#             a          b            c
# 1: -0.1069952  0.1115983  0.004603111
# 2:  0.3228771 -0.8400846 -0.517207530
# 3: -1.6072728 -0.2727947 -1.880067477
# 4:  0.1715614 -0.3864995 -0.214938065
# 5:  1.8233350 -1.0786569  0.744678084
# 6:  0.2366026 -0.6166318 -0.380029253
# 7:  0.2373992  0.2251559  0.462555116
# 8: -0.1075611 -1.0418174 -1.149378504
# 9:  1.6742520 -0.5635583  1.110693774
#10:  2.4733842  2.1091365  4.582520731

#[[2]]
#             a           b           c
# 1: -0.8332617  1.67201117  0.83874947
# 2:  1.3688393  1.12168046  2.49051974
# 3:  1.0208642 -1.18482073 -0.16395650
# 4:  0.6784662  2.15979872  2.83826493
# 5: -0.4351644 -0.04629453 -0.48145894
# 6:  1.3133550 -1.03423308  0.27912197
# 7:  1.0143396 -0.84787780  0.16646185
# 8: -0.9622108  0.92338456 -0.03882627
# 9: -0.3106202  1.08886031  0.77824008
#10:  0.7602507 -0.08996701  0.67028370
```

---

Or wrap with `invisible` along with `lapply`

```
invisible(lapply(dts, function(dt) {
                  dt[, ':=' (c = a + b)]
     }))
```

Comment: I would like to avoid additional packages with the solution

Comment: @Mxblsdl I also provided a `base R` solutioin

Answer (score 0):

Using set:

`for (i in seq_along(dts)) set(dts[[i]], j = "c", value = dts[[i]]$a + dts[[i]]$b)`